# Shadow of a Tesseract

Tags: geometry

I understand that the shadow of an object is one dimension less than the original object.

What what the shadow of a tesseract look like? Are there any real world examples?

Edit:

I found this, the Grande Arche in Paris which is a hypercube. Is this a true tesseract, and does it have a 3D shadow?

Comment: I don't remember how the base of Grande Arche looks like. The other part of it does look like the projection of a tesseract into $\mathbb{R}^3$ along one of its symmetry axis. Along a general axis, the shadow/projection (either orthographic or perspective) of tesseract is something like what is shown in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-WyreE9ZkI).

Answer (score 0):

Undestanding "shadow" as projection, see at Wolfram:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tesseract.html

and many other sites:

http://slumathcsclub.wordpress.com/2011/10/24/4-dimensional-hypercubes/

Comment: Presumably that's what is meant, but physically the identification of "shadow" as projection is doubtful since light propagates in $3$ dimensions, not $4$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, interesting twist. But why the restriction on the 4D-light in the 4D space?

Comment: None of those links talk about shadows

Comment: @user12321, define "shadow".

Comment: @user12321, maybe interesting: http://www.ia.hiof.no/~borres/cgraph/explain/shadow/p-shadow.html.

Comment: @Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla I mean if a beam of light were shone on an object, the darkness behind the object where the light could not pass through would be the shadow.

Comment: If the whole tesseract is opaque, the shadow is the outer border of the projections (will vary with the relative orientation). Warning: see the comment by @RobertIsrael.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla The thing is though, neither of those links talk about projection either, from what I can see.

Comment: @Jack M So therefore, although on the topic of tesseracts, neither are really related to what I'm looking for.